# Unable to install Flaskr in Python37

Tags: python

I am trying to install Flaskr and its giving me issues. I am using Python 3.7 in my virtual evnv.

```
(venv) C:\Code\Angular\xxxx>pip install flaskr==1.1
Collecting flaskr==1.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flaskr==1.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flaskr==1.1
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, `Flaskr` is the name given to an example app in tutorial. It is NOT a module. If you want to install `Flask` (module), just use `pip install Flask`

Comment: are you sure there is version `1.1` ? `pip search flaskr` shows me only `1.0.0`